# How to mock IOptionsSnapshot instance for testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, asp.net-core-1.1

I have class `AbClass` that get with asp.net core built-in DI instance of `IOptionsSnapshot<AbOptions>` (dynamic configuration).
now I want to test this class.

I'm trying to instantiate `AbClass` class in test class, but I have no idea how can I instantiate an instance of `IOptionsSnapshot<AbOptions>` to inject into the constructor of `AbClass`.

I tried use `Mock<IOptionsSnapshot<AbOptions>>.Object`, but I need to set some values to this instance, since in AbClass the code is using this values (`var x = _options.cc.D1`).

so I have a code like

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    ["Ab:cc:D1"] = "https://",
    ["Ab:cc:D2"] = "123145854170887"
});
var config = builder.Build();
var options = new AbOptions();
config.GetSection("Ab").Bind(options);
```

but I dont know how to link this Options and the IOptionsSnapshot mock.

AbClass:

```
public class AbClass {
    private readonly AbOptions _options;

    public AbClass(IOptionsSnapshot<AbOptions> options) {
        _options = options.Value;    
    }
    private void x(){var t = _options.cc.D1}
}
```

my test instantiate this class:

```
var service = new AbClass(new Mock???)
```

and need to test a method in `AbClass` that call `x()`, but it throw `ArgumentNullException` when it on `_options.cc.D1`

Comment: Good question! With `IOptions<T>` there's a static `Create` method on the `Options` class but there's no equivalent jumping out at me for `IOptionsSnapshot<T>`. Curious what the answer is.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should be able to mock up the interface and create an instance of the options class for the test. As I am unaware of the nested classes for the options class I am making a broad assumption.

[Documentation: IOptionsSnapshot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#ioptionssnapshot)

```
//Arrange
//Instantiate options and nested classes
//making assumptions here about nested types
var options = new AbOptions(){
    cc = new cc {
        D1 = "https://",
        D2 = "123145854170887"
    }
};
var mock = new Mock<IOptionsSnapshot<AbOptions>>();
mock.Setup(m => m.Value).Returns(options);

var service = new AbClass(mock.Object);
```

Access to the nested values should now return proper values instead of NRE

Answer (score 12):

A generic way:

```
    public static IOptionsSnapshot<T> CreateIOptionSnapshotMock<T>(T value) where T : class, new()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IOptionsSnapshot<T>>();
        mock.Setup(m => m.Value).Returns(value);
        return mock.Object;
    }
```

usage:

```
var mock = CreateIOptionSnapshotMock(new AbOptions(){
    cc = new cc {
        D1 = "https://",
        D2 = "123145854170887"
    }
});
```